# Time trigger background task without lock screen.(WinRT)

Tags: windows-runtime, background-task

Is there any way to run time trigger background task without App. being at the lock screen?

Answer (score 1):

TimeTrigger background tasks require lock screen access on Windows. This is not required on Windows Phone.

See [How to run a background task on a timer (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977059.aspx):

> On Windows, a background task will only run using a TimeTrigger if you
>   have requested that your app be placed on the lock screen with a call
>   to RequestAccessAsync and the user accepts the prompt. On Windows
>   Phone, you must call RequestAccessAsync, but there is no user prompt.

Comment: Is there any other ways to have periodic background task without adding the App. on the lock screen?

Comment: Hi Rob, just wonder if you know if this is the same case on Windows 10 Mobile?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 this restriction has been removed.
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-626